# React doesn't rerender component despite state modification

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of cards which I want to filter/sort, using 4 different select / input fields.

For 3 of the 4 filters, things work great. Cards are successfully filtered and sorted, and the filters can be combined with no problem.

On the first one though, I have to click it twice, or click it once then activate another filter, to see the changes in my cards.

I do not understand why this particular filter does not trigger the rerender of the cards because like all the others filters, its value is updated in the state, which looks like this :

```
 const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    orderByFilter: null, // doesn't work the first time
    titleFilter: null,
    dateFilter: '',
    searchFilter: '',
  });
```

What I did to address the asynchronous state update is that I watch from changes in filters in a useEffect hook, to update the filtered data. Again, works fine for the other 3 filters.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredData(filterCards(dataCards, filters));
    // forceUpdate();
  }, [filters]);
```

**I am able to make it work for the 4 filters when I trigger a force update after `setFilteredData` :**

```
const forceUpdate = React.useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1] as () => void;
```

But it feels like a hack to me and shows that I didn't understand what the real problem is.

**Is there a way to make this work without this force update ?**

PS : Edited the code to avoid indexation by search engines, as this is semi-sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that for the order filter you're using `sort`, which sorts the array [in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), so in the end you get the same array, but with sorted values, which doesn't get picked up by React as a change, i.e. does not trigger a render. To fix this, when initialising the filter array, try using it's copy:

```
 let filteredArray = [...valueListCards];
```

Also the approach of saving the filtered data to state is not optimal, as it results in these kinds of bugs, plus you need to keep the state in sync with the actual data. A better idea would be to [derive the state](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it), which is basically applying the filters at render.

Comment: I didn't know sorting an array wasn't a change to React eyes, it was indeed the issue here, thank you, marking the issue as resolved.

I appreciate the concern on saving the filtered date in the state. I'm not fully grasping yet how I would be able to derive the state, but I'm going to look deeply into it.